Convert dataframe to specific list (index)
I would like to know if it is possible to convert this kind of dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame([['Value1', 1], ['Value3', 3], ['Value4', 4]], columns=['Value', 'Type'])

Into a list which consider column "Type" as index of list and "Value" as value of list like this(no index in the dataframe involves no value):
List= ["","Value1", "", "Value3","Value4"]

I can create this list by parsing the dataframe but I would like to know if there is a better way to achieve this.
Currently there is the parsing:
last=df["Type"].max()
liste=[]
index_list=0
index_df=0
while index_list<=last:
    if df["Type"].iloc[index_df]==index_list:
        liste.insert(index_list, df["Value"].iloc[index_df])
        index_df=index_df+1
    else:
        liste.insert(index_list, "")
    index_list=index_list+1

Thank you

Please don't share pictures of dataframes, you should copy it and format it accordingly. Also, at least you can share your attempt.

The pictures have been transformed as text as reuestes, i guess

Maybe something like this: result_list = pd.Series(df['Value'].values, index=df['Type']).reindex(range(0, df['Type'].max() + 1), fill_value="").tolist()

why have you not shown how you created the list by parsing ?

Added the current code of parsing dataframe

@Ksartor Does code from my previous comment work for you? If so I can write up an answer. If not, please share what's wrong.

Sorry it did not work because it is not general. I update the dataset to be more general . Thank you for your help

@Ksartor In what sense it's not general? It works for example you've given and type of problem you've described. For what example does it not work? What needs to be more general?

It does not work for a dataframe with Type 0, 2 and 4 per example (i.e. non continuous value of Type)

@Ksartor, does the example shown below  not answer  it?

not sure if you have typos in your desired/expected result or that you've actually added a 'Value1' entry manually to List ? (only you know)!
df = pd.DataFrame([['Value2', 2], ['Value3', 3], ['Value4', 4]], columns=['Value', 'Type'])
print(df)

alist = ["", "", "Value1"] + df['Value'].tolist()
print(alist)

produces
    Value  Type
0  Value2     2
1  Value3     3
2  Value4     4

['', '', 'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4']


